# What's wrong with this code by objective-c

Tags: objective-c

【question】The code1 can not be compiled, but code2 has no problem. So why?
【code1】

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool{
        NSLog(@"\nProgram is working........\n");
        int a=15;
        int b=55;
        int sum=0;
        sum=a+b;
        NSLog(@"The equality : %i + %i= %i\n",a,b,sum);
        NSLog(@"Program is over!\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

【code2】

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"\nProgram is working........\n");
    int a=15;
    int b=55;
    int sum=0;
    sum=a+b;
    NSLog(@"The equality : %i + %i= %i\n",a,b,sum);
    NSLog(@"Program is over!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

【notice】

### This programming environment is established under win7 by GNU Gcc.

希望各位说的详细些，非常感谢！

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@autoreleasepool` construct is a feature of Apple's LLVM compiler that's not available in GCC.

Comment: Another question:what's meaning of this sentence---->NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];